# TweenMax js rotation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, rotation, gsap

I have this bit of code which basically defines a loop that rotates an image at the end of a transition: http://jsfiddle.net/bolaoch8/k8XtU/1/

```
$('#avion').css('left', '0%');

var animacionAvion = TweenMax.to($('#avion'), 5, {css:{left:'100%'}, delay:0, repeat:-1, yoyo:true});

setInterval(giraAvion, 5000);

var rotationValue = 180;

function giraAvion()
{
    console.log('giraAvion a:', rotationValue);
    TweenMax.to($('#avion'), 0.8, {css:{transform:'rotate('+rotationValue+'deg)'}, delay:5});
    rotationValue == 180?rotationValue = 0:rotationValue = 180;
}
giraAvion();
```

Just wondering why the second time the image rotates it does that weird thing... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use TimelineMax, wich will help you to chain tweens : http://api.greensock.com/js/

It will render your animation much simpler.

```
var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});    
tl.to($('#avion'), 5, {css:{left:'100%'}});
tl.to($('#avion'), 0.8, {css:{rotation:180}});
tl.to($('#avion'), 5, {css:{left:'0%'}});
tl.to($('#avion'), 0.8, {css:{rotation:0}});
tl.play();
```

No more intervals and functions!

I modifed your jsfiddle to get the power of it :
http://jsfiddle.net/xavier_seignard/k8XtU/3/

Comment: That's it! It totaly solved it and works perfectly fluid! Thansk a lot!